# How to use dynamo DB session handler with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

According to [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/dynamodb-session-handler.html), registering dynamodb session handler let you use PHP sessions like normal, but I try registering the dynamo session handler and autoloading it but that doesn't seems to be working.

Any guidance in order to make it work?